# Sumar todos los valores y agregar el valor al final

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Tengo el siguiente código en Python:

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi
t = np.linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,16300) #Creo un vector de 16300 puntos de -2*pi a 2*pi
x = np.sinc(t) 
print(x)
```

Quiero sumar algebraicamente todos los puntos de x y agregar ese dato al final de un nuevo arreglo.

Por lo tanto, el nuevo arreglo tendrá 16301 puntos.

Comment: Para sumar todos los elementos del array basta con usar `np.sum(x)`. Ahora bién, ¿a que nuevo arreglo lo quieres agregar? ¿Como creas ese arreglo y que datos contiene además de la suma?

Comment: Lo quiero agregar al arreglo que ya tenía, pero sin modificar el arreglo x, se podria crear una nueva variable y por ejemplo

Comment: Es decir, ¿quieres obtener un nuevo array con el contenido de `x` más la suma de los valores de `x` al final? Si tienes (a modo de ejemplo) `x = [1, 2, 3]` quieres obtener algo como `y  = [1, 2, 3, 6]`

Comment: sí, exacto,  es lo que estoy buscando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente usa `numpy.sum` para realizar la suma y [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) para crear un nuevo array con los valores de `x` agregando la suma al final:

```
y = np.append(x, np.sum(x))
```

Ejemplo simple:

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
>
> >>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
> >>> b = np.append(a, np.sum(a))
> >>> b
> array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 10])
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó a resolver el problema, pero ahora tengo otro problema con ese nuevo arreglo, tengo que enviarlo como una cadena de 16 bits, estoy intentando esto: from array import array  a = array('H',b)  suponiendo que es es el nuevo elemento a enviar convertido como datos de 16 bits, y b el arreglo que ya tenia con la sumatoria, el comando array('H',b) solo me acepta numeros sin signo, como podria enviarle numeros enteros negativos?

Comment: basta con poner la H en minuscula, muchas gracias :D